# Scala Spark handles Double.NaN differently in dataframe and dataset

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset, nan

In tests, I'm trying to convert dataframe/datasets into sets and compare it. E.g.

```
actualResult.collect.toSet should be(expectedResult.collect.toSet)
```

I noticed some facts regarding `Double.NaN` value.

1. In Scala, `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` returns false.
2. In spark `NaN == NaN` is true. ([offical doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#nan-semantics))

But I couldn't figure out **why dataframe and dataset behaves differently**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Example").master("local").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  val dataSet = spark.createDataset(Seq(Book("book 1", Double.NaN)))

  // Compare Set(Book(book 1,NaN)) to itself
  println(dataSet.collect.toSet == dataSet.collect.toSet) //false, why?

  // Compare Set([book 1,NaN]) to itself
  println(dataSet.toDF().collect.toSet == dataSet.toDF().collect.toSet) //true, why?
}

case class Book (title: String, price: Double)
```

Here's my question. Appreciate any insights.

1. How does it happen in code? (where the `equals` gets overridden? etc..)
2. Any reasons behind this design? Is there a better paradigm to assert dataset/dataframe in tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few points which I want to share related to this topic.

1. When you do `dataSet.collect.toSet` you collect it as **Set[Book]** and when you do a comparison between two sets of book objects.

The individual (book)objects equal method is used for comparison which you define in **Book Case class**.
**that is why `println(dataSet.collect.toSet == dataSet.collect.toSet)` returned false because of `Double.NaN == Double.NaN returns false`.**

2. When you do `dataSet.toDF().collect.toSet` you collect it as **Set[[Row]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html)**

when you do **toDF** spark will convert**(i.e serialize Book then deserialize to javaType fields **Row**)** Book class to **Row** in this process it also does some conversions on fields using [RowEncoders](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/RowEncoder.scala).

**All the Primitive fields are converted to java types using the below code in RowEncoder.scala**

```
def apply(schema: StructType): ExpressionEncoder[Row] = {
    val cls = classOf[Row]
    **val inputObject = BoundReference(0, ObjectType(cls), nullable = true)
    val serializer = serializerFor(AssertNotNull(inputObject, Seq("top level row object")), schema)
    val deserializer = deserializerFor(schema)**
    new ExpressionEncoder[Row](
      schema,
      flat = false,
      serializer.asInstanceOf[CreateNamedStruct].flatten,
      deserializer,
      ClassTag(cls))
  }
```

if you check the source code of **Double.java and Float.java** equal method. comparison of NAN will return true. that is why Row objects comparison will return true. and `println(dataSet.toDF().collect.toSet == dataSet.toDF().collect.toSet)` is true.

```
<li>If {@code d1} and {@code d2} both represent
     *     {@code Double.NaN}, then the {@code equals} method
     *     returns {@code true}, even though
     *     {@code Double.NaN==Double.NaN} has the value
     *     {@code false}.
     * <li>If {@code d1} represents {@code +0.0} while
     *     {@code d2} represents {@code -0.0}, or vice versa,
     *     the {@code equal} test has the value {@code false},
     *     even though {@code +0.0==-0.0} has the value {@code true}.
     * </ul>
```

**Sorry if I'm grammatically wrong.